# Accidentally connected iCloud to my work machine and now I have a huge mess on my hands.

Tags: icloud, hard-drive

So I don't really remember how this happened, but during some sort of update I accidentally signed into icloud with my personal account instead of my work account. Somewhere in this process I actually activated icloud, so now ALL of my work stuff from my work machine is in iCloud, I'm not entirely sure how to get it back on my desktop without also putting a bunch of personal info and documents on the machine, and I'm hoping to fix this before anyone notices a massive change in my bandwidth usage. Any ideas for how to do this?

Comment: I think your main option is to clear out everything manually from a personal computer. My understanding of iCloud is a fairly one-way action. You can remove the data from your device when signing out but that is the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what I ended up doing was disconnecting the machine from iCloud. I couldn't really do anything about the data that had been transferred (I figure once it's been downloaded the damage is already done) but I was able to find evertyhing by going to

User > iCloud Drive (Archive) and then subfolders for the machine. Unfortunately it also downloaded a LOT of personal data but I just deleted everything except for those particular subfolders. I *was* able to get everything back, so I guess that's a good thing, but I still never ever want to deal with this ever again. I'm going back to only using Dropbox.

Comment: People keep forgetting (not that you did) that iCloud is a syncing solution.  It's not primarily a backup solution so any time you connect a computer, it's going to start syncing the data across.

Comment: Yeah. Honestly I don't have a whole lot of faith in iCloud in general (and especially not now). My issue was that I derped and signed into my personal account on the work machine by accident. Never. Again.

Answer (score 1):

Did you logged out from iCloud on your working machine?
First of all try to do this: System Preferences > iCloud > Sign Out

Comment: Yeah, I logged out as soon as I noticed, but all of my data was already in iCloud